# hasMany without foreignKey

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to do a hasMany model association without a foreignKey, but with a condition.

I have the following tables.

- clients (id, name)
- teams (id, name)
- projects (id, team_id, client_id)

If there is a project with `team_id = x` and `client_id = y`, I want the client Y to belongTo team X.

I have the following code in Team.php Model, but I have no idea how to do the condition.

```
public $hasMany = array( 
    'Client' => array(
        'className' => 'Client',
        'foreignKey' => false,
        'conditions' => '(HOW DO I DO CONDITION)'
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a hasAndBelongsToMany with projects as the join table.

However, I think you want to use the [hasMany through](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through) join since *I am assuming* your projects table has other columns.

That link describes what you want to do. Replace the CakePHP's example Student and Course models with your Client and Team. Instead of the CourseMembership model, use your Project model.

Comment: this isn't what i want to do. i want the client y to belong to team x, if there is a project of that client y with the team x.